# Unable to load Cert into OpenLDAP userCertificate attribute

Tags: ldap, certificate, certificate-authority

I having troubles to add particular cert into userCertificate attribute (DER encoded certificate) in standard scheme of openldap-servers-2.4.39-3.el7.x86_64 running on  Centos7

Slapd uses:

```
include        /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include        /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include        /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
```

I use  Apache Dir Studio (latest version: 2.0.0.v20130628 at 2015.07.30 )

Then I do Load cert into userCertificate attribute it shows all cert fields but then I press OK LDAP returns error:

```
#!ERROR [LDAP: error code 21 - userCertificate;binary: value #0 normalization failed]
```

Command:

```
openssl x509 -in ./shit_cert.cer -inform DER -text
```

works ok without errors.

Other certs from this CA loads ok into this salpd userCertificate attribute.

BTW it is Russian Crypto-Pro CA ( http://www.cryptopro.ru/products/ca ) cert and i guess this particular one has some x509 extensions.

Other certs from this CA loads corectly.

Can one help how to work it out please

**p.s.**

If I use command line to load cert a get similar error

```
cat ./cer.ldif 

dn: cn=anisimov,o=000,dc=aaa,dc=bbb
changetype: modify
add: userCertificate;binary
userCertificate;binary:< file:///root/wrong_certs/shit_cert.cer


# ldapmodify -v -x -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=aaa,dc=bbb" -f ./cer.ldif
ldap_initialize( <DEFAULT> )
Enter LDAP Password:
add userCertificate;binary:
        NOT ASCII (1831 bytes)
modifying entry "cn=anisimov,o=000,dc=aaa,dc=bbb"
ldap_modify: Invalid syntax (21)
        additional info: userCertificate;binary: value #0 normalization failed
```

slap LogLevel -1 in slapd.conf file tells me following :

```
авг 03 14:33:36 centos7.000.ru slapd[13909]: conn=1000 op=13 MOD dn="cn=anisimov,o=000,dc=aaa,dc=bbb"
авг 03 14:33:36 centos7.000.ru slapd[13909]: conn=1000 op=13 MOD attr=userCertificate;binary
авг 03 14:33:36 centos7.000.ru slapd[13909]: <= str2entry NULL (ssyn_normalize 21)
авг 03 14:33:36 centos7.000.ru slapd[13909]: conn=1000 op=13 RESULT tag=103 err=21 text=userCertificate;binary: value #0 normalization failed
авг 03 14:33:36 centos7.000.ru slapd[13909]: conn=1000 op=14 SRCH base="cn=anisimov,o=000,dc=aaa,dc=bbb" scope=0 deref=3 filter="(objectClass=*)"
авг 03 14:33:36 centos7.000.ru slapd[13909]: conn=1000 op=14 SRCH attr=*
авг 03 14:33:36 centos7.000.ru slapd[13909]: conn=1000 op=14 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
```

Comment: Did you try to parse the cert with http://lapo.it/asn1js/?

Comment: It does not complain on ASN1 or produce any warning. Looks correct ASN1 file.

Comment: So we have to use OpenDJ. ApacheDS also works,